# How to use groupby pandas dataframe with iterrows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to make calculations over the rows of a pandas dataframe, but I need to ake these calculations by group, so I used groupBy but when I used iterrows, I got this issue

**AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'iterrows'**

Please anyone can help me?

Thank

Comment: Hi, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Please also show us what you have tried: the actual code. In general, `df.iterrows` is unlikely to be the best option for your calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your problem correctly here is the answer.
iterrows came from a pandas dataframe object. when you call groupby on a dataframe, you have DataFrameGroupBy object.

so you need to iterate over DataFrameGroupBy then call iterrow for each group of it.

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[1,1,1,0,0]}
d = pd.DataFrame(d)
d_agg = d.groupby('b')
for name,group in d_agg:
    print('group: ',name)
    for row,data in group.iterrows():
        print(row,data)
```

if you have further question let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary warning: You should refrain from using `iterrows`, it's slow and can be replaced by vectorial code in most cases. When it cannot, there are often still better alternatives.**

That said, if you want to use an iterrows logic, you would need to encapsulate your logic in a function and combine it with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
def logic(g):
    # this is a dummy example
    # you would never use iterrows
    # for this simple operation
    for idx, row in g.iterrows():
        g.loc[idx, 'value'] += 10
    return g

out = df.groupby('group', group_keys=False).apply(logic)
```

Output:

```
  group  value
0     a     10
1     a     11
2     a     12
3     a     13
4     a     14
5     b     15
6     b     16
7     b     17
8     c     18
9     c     19
```